# Evaluating simple integrations according to Lebesgue

Tags: integration

One difference between Riemann's and Lebesgue's approach of integrations is that Riemann partitions domain of integration, whereas Lebesgue partitions the range of the function.

I will consider two simple examples of integration, which by method of Lebesgue, I would like to evaluate. No book on Lebesgue is illustrating Lebesgue method through some examples. (I know the Dirichlet function, and its Lebesgue integration; but that function is not Riemann integrable). Here, I will consider function, not too complicated and not too simple (like step function), and try to evaluate its integration by Lebesgue's approach.

The functions are $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in [0,1]$.

**Question:** How do we evaluate $\int_0^1 f$ by Lebesgue's approach?

Answer (score 2):

Lebesgue and Riemann "approaches" becomes symmetric if you add one dimension. For example, for $f(x)=x$
$$
\int_0^1x\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^x 1\,dydx=\int_D 1\,dxdy 
$$
where $D$ is the triangular with the corners $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$. Clearly the double integral can be calculated by reducing to iterated integrals by two ways (*Fubini theorem*) - the one above (first in $y$ then in $x$) or the opposite (first in $x$ then in $y$) which corresponds to Lebesgue partitioning
$$
\int_D 1\,dxdy=\int_0^1\int_y^1 1\,dxdy=\int_0^1(1-y)\,dy.
$$
Here $1-y$ is exactly the length (the *measure*) of the interval $f(x)>y$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=x^2$. The "Lebesgue approach" you mention is most clearly seen in the formula 
$$
\int_0^1 x^2\, dx = \int_0^\infty \left\lvert \{x^2> t\}\cap\{0<x<1\}\right\rvert\, dt,$$
the $\lvert\cdot\rvert$ denoting Lebesgue measure. You can compute directly the integral in the right hand side and check that you obtain the correct result $\frac{1}{3}$.